# Call the activity in background and don't show it

Tags: android, android-activity, background-foreground

I had two activities A and B. I want to run the Activity B when user opens the activity A but i don't want to show the Activity B on foreground. If activity B is running also i want to show the activity A only not the B activity. For this i used `moveTaskToBack(true);` in activity B. When i'm using `moveTaskToBack(true);` my app was closing automatically (Going to background). Any one know how to achieve this?

Comment: You need a [service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: Why are you using an activity to not show anything?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? May be this is a hack and there can be other ways to achieve what you tryna do

Comment: instead of activity B use service it will resolve your query

Comment: @nobalG I tired by using service also but i failed to achieve this. When i saw the Vickyexpert comment i got an idea

Comment: @Vickyexpert thank you for your comment. I'll try as you said.

Comment: Activity is designed to show content. You should not use Activity if you want not to show content.

Comment: @VladMatvienko ya it's true. As of now i misunderstood now i'm going to implement Activity B in service. Thank for your comment